# Full postback on select & remove within update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

I'm having issues with the asp.net textbox within an update panel. It works perfectly fine when adding or removing each individual character but if I highlight all of the text within the textbox, and then remove it a full postback occurs, not a partial postback which is expected.

Why is this happening? I haven't found anything related to this particular problem so it's likely I'm doing something wrong.

Example aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updExample" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptExample" runat="server" .... >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExample" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" Text='<%# Eval("Example") %>' OnTextChanged="txtExample_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Example TextChanged Event:

```
protected void txtExample_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   updExample.Update();
}
```

***Additional Notes:***

- Switching UpdateMode to 'Always' doesn't work.

Comment: if you add trigger for your update panel??  [link](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1749411)  learn here

Comment: I already did this within the repeater ItemDataBound event. However, after thinking about it ItemCreated is better suited so the triggers are reassigned. After tweaking with this it seems to work now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Karthikeyan Nagaraj** pointed out in the comments to try adding triggers alongside what I already had. I did in fact already have this, however, I was assigning the trigger in the ItemDataBound event which I realized was incorrect after reinvestigating. The ItemCreated event was much more suited.

I had no issues finding the control in the ItemCreated event, however adding a new async postback trigger to the update panel gave me grief and said the control couldn't be found when changing the text. To resolve this, I used the script managers RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(); method as shown below.

```
protected void rptExample_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   var input = e.item.FindControl("txtExample");

   if (input != null) {
     ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
     sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(input);
   }
}
```